# How to resolve React - Firebase - Protected Routes is not a <Route> component issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I was following a react firebase tutorial based on
"firebase": "^7.14.4",    "react": "^16.13.1",

My new Version is:  "firebase": "^9.22.1",  "react": "^18.2.0",

I read this stackoverflow post , but it looks too verbose and not sure how to integrate in my app
[Protected routes in React using firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74874767/protected-routes-in-react-using-firebase)

```
  <Route
    path="/details"
    element={
      isAuthenticated && role === "admin" ? (
        <PhoneDetails />
      ) : (
        <Navigate replace to="/" />
      )
    }
  />
```

My current Protected route is

```
    <ProtectedRoute isAuthed={!!user} isLoading={isLoading} path='/' exact>
      <SomePage />
    </ProtectedRoute>
```

Error:

> [ProtectedRoute] is not a  component. All component children of
>  must be a  or <React.Fragment>
> invariant@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72359:11

A route like this

> ```
> <Router>
>   <Switch>
>     <Route path='/sign-in'>
>       <SignInPage />
>     </Route>
>  </. .>
> ```

I now

> <Route path='/sign-in' element={<  SignInPage />}/>

The protected route code is (using navigate instead of use history etc etc)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuthed, isLoading, ...props }) => {
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (!isAuthed) {
    return <Navigate to='/sign-in' />
  }

  return (
    <Route {...props} />
  );
}
```

But how can I get ProtectedRoute working in my App.js?

Comment: Just got it working - <Route path='/' exact element={<ProtectedRoute><SomePage /></ProtectedRoute>} />  and changing protected route  export const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { isLoading, user } = useAuth(); .....as is in betwen... return  children;